# Make long value as date and format it in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, date, thymeleaf

I have this line in my Thymeleaf template.

```
<td th:text="${activity.loggedTimestamp}"></td>
```

I want to convert this long value into a date before formatting it. If it was already a date I would have done this:

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(activity.loggedTimestamp)}"></td>
```

But, since its a long value, I want to make it a date first.

I found some related methods in the documentation. But, not matching with my requirements.

```
/*
 * Create date (java.util.Date) objects from its components
 */
${#dates.create(year,month,day)}
${#dates.create(year,month,day,hour,minute)}
${#dates.create(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)}
${#dates.create(year,month,day,hour,minute,second,millisecond)}

/*
 * Create a date (java.util.Date) object for the current date and time
 */
${#dates.createNow()}

/*
 * Create a date (java.util.Date) object for the current date (time set to 00:00)
 */
${#dates.createToday()}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [ThymeLeaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#variables):

> We already mentioned that `${...}` **expressions are in fact OGNL (Object-Graph Navigation Language) expressions** executed on the map of variables contained in the context.
>
> For detailed info about OGNL syntax and features, you should read the OGNL Language Guide at: http://commons.apache.org/ognl/

So you follow that link to the [OGNL documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Calling_Constructors):

> **You can create new objects as in Java, with the `new` operator**. One difference is that you must specify the fully qualified class name for classes other than those in the java.lang package.
>
> This is only true with the default ClassResolver in place. With a custom class resolver packages can be mapped in such a way that more Java-like references to classes can be made. Refer to the OGNL Developer's Guide for details on using `ClassResolver` class (for example, `new java.util.ArrayList()`, rather than simply `new ArrayList()`).
>
> OGNL chooses the right constructor to call using the same procedure it uses for overloaded method calls.

**Conclusion**

You write:

```
<td th:text="${#dates.format(new java.util.Date(activity.loggedTimestamp))}"></td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: I had to do this, or else I was getting exception saying activity.loggedTimestamp was null:      <span th:text="${#dates.format(new java.util.Date('_'_${activity.loggedTimestamp}'_'_ * 1000l))}"></span>

Comment: Very elegant answer, indeed. Claps.

Comment: is there any option to pass language?

Comment: @Amit Option where? For what language? Did you check the *documentation*?

Comment: i want to set language to english in this line.
 <td th:text="${#dates.format(new java.util.Date(activity.loggedTimestamp))}"></td>

Comment: @Amit Do a web search for how to control the `Locale` in Thymeleaf.

Comment: i already passing Local to this template. but don't want to apply that language to this line. So i want specific language to this line.

Comment: @Amit That is not supported by Thymeleaf. See https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-extras-java8time/issues/5

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use directly on HTML Thymeleaf page:

```
<span th:text="'Label of Date: ' + ${#dates.format(new java.util.Date(activity.loggedTimestamp), 'dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm')}"></span>
```