# Thymeleaf parse preprocessing String to date and format it

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, date-format

I have Model Attribute that contains a list of properties.

The value which I want to format is similar to this string: `2012-07-16T00:00:00`.

I try to use

```
<p th:text="${#temporals.format(${myData.mdProperties.get('completionDate')}, 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></p>
```

The parsing keeps failing. Then I thought I should convert String to date using custom dialect but it is complicated. Is there any simpler solution?

I tried to convert the string to date based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944180/make-long-value-as-date-and-format-it-in-thymeleaf) but it failed:

```
<p th:text="${#temporals.format(new java.util.Date(${{myData.mdProperties.get('completionDate')}}), 'dd-MM-yyyy')}"></p>
```

Comment: Could you add the error/exception to your question? It is not clear what is failing.

Answer (score 5):

You have too many brackets in each of your expressions. In general, you should never have nested `${ ... }` expressions (excpept when doing preprocessing).

Also, you'll need to create a simple date format to first parse your dates.  This worked for my test case:

```
<th:block th:with="sdf = ${new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss')}">
    <p th:text="${#dates.format(sdf.parse(myData.mdProperties.get('completionDate')), 'dd-MM-yyyy')}" />
</th:block>
```

Comment: I tried the above. But it gave me an error- `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss')`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, I needed to set min attribute for a `input type="datetime-local"`, maybe it could be useful

```
th:attr="min=${#strings.substring(#dates.formatISO(#dates.createNow()),0,16)}"
```

that set: `min="2022-01-06T19:47"`