# How to use Thymeleaf and/or spring expression language to convert a string e.g. "2018-02-21" into a date format dd/mm/yyyy (e.g. "21/02/2018")

Tags: date, format, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am creating a template that needs to format a string variable that is in format yyyy-MM-dd as a date in format dd/MM/yyyy. I have successfully managed this with the below however this doesn't feel right...

```
<p th:text="${testDate != '' ? #dates.format(#strings.replace(testDate,'-','/'),'dd/MM/yyyy') : ''}"></p>
```

Also as additional problem sometimes the date field can come across as a time e.g. "09:03:21" but I can worry about that later.

The date string is retrieved from a service and the format cannot be changed.

Thanks for any help

Comment: One way to do it would be like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52169389

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<p th:text="${testDate != '' ? #temporals.format(testDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'): ''}"></p>
```

Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39860643/formatting-date-in-thymeleaf) for better understanding!

Comment: Can't get that to work. I am using a Microservice that combines the HTML template and Thymeleaf so have no control at the other end. However the below does work so it is obviously something to do with the fact the date is in the format yyyy-MM-dd.... <p th:text="${#dates.format(testDate2, 'dd-MMM-yy')}"></p>
That works if testDate2="10/10/2018" but fails if it is "2018-10-10"

Comment: You want to show date format like `2018-10-10` or `10/10/2018` ?

Comment: @Blingers As you are working on microservice then definitely you are consuming API, aren't you?

Comment: Yes consuming. The api returns 2018-10-10 and I need to convert to 10/10/2018. Thanks

Comment: Do you have any DTO where you mapping your API?

Comment: @Blingers If you have DTO where you are putting object after calling API please post that DTO.

Comment: @Blingers Haven't got any response!